# Does Ubuntu automatically boot when near a source of internet (router, phone data)

Tags: boot, networking, last-command

Looking at the "last" command, I see that my laptop booted up a few times in the past couple months, one time for six hours.

It was sitting in an empty place, and I noticed that every time listed where it booted up, were times where I visited the place.

I had it connected to data on my phone at one point before I stored it in this empty place.

I am curious, was the laptop booting up because it detected my phone every time I visited the place it was stored? Is there a way to check if this is what's happening specifically? Is it possible to disable this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: It's most likely the Wake-on-LAN feature in the BIOS ... Is your computer Ethernet port connected to a router via cable? ... Some WiFi devices support Wake-on-LAN as well, so yes your phone can be the reason ... Check your BIOS and disable that feature ... see [this for example](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000027615/intel-nuc.html)

Comment: Thanks @Raffa, much appreciated.

The laptop was not connected to a router, it was sitting inside of a luggage bag.

I'll try to remember to come back to this and leave extra clarification when I can, but for now I can't get into BIOS to check if the Wake-on-LAN feature is the cause here. I think I messed up somehow when installing Ubuntu, and I get some kind of error when I hit f-keys on start up, rather than the BIOS.

Comment: WOL only works if you set it up and it requires setting up a router too. It does not work out of the box. It could also be WOK (wake on keyboard) though where you accidentally have a key pressed.  That one is straight hardware and not OS dependent and does not require a setup except for activating it.